# When I was brushing my teeth

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, number-sequence

I came up with this puzzle in the morning when I was brushing my teeth.

> 3, 8, 4, 6, 5, 8, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, ?

**What should the next number  be?**
Give your reasoning as well.

**HINT:**

> Even number position represent letters

**NOTE**: I have edited my sequence, and the answer is not 8.

Comment: is it important that you were brushing your teeth? or are you trying to tell us that good oral hygiene makes you better at creating puzzles?

Comment: @AmruthA no,it is not in OEIS.

Comment: Is this the order in which you brush your teeth by number? ;) Just kidding.

Comment: Tooth 8 was particularly dirty. ;-)

Comment: Are you sure its not 8. Looks like an 8 to me lol

Comment: I guess 7 might work if it's symmetrical about the 8's. Suppose that's about the laziest answer one can give.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> 7

And the pattern is

> 3=Triangle
> 4=Square
> 5=Pentagon
> 6=Hexagon
> 7=Heptagon
> 8=Octagon

And

> The even position numbers are the number of letters in the names of the regular polygons with those numbers of sides. Triangle has 7 letters, Square has 5, etc.

Comment: What does "all contains equilateral triangle" mean?

Comment: It mean ....rhombus also contain four sides.

Comment: So you mean "Each one is a [regular polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon)"?

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer

> 7 ?

Because

> As your hint says, every even number is a letter, giving 3H, 4F, 5H, 6G, 7H, 8?

Then

> I thought, why don't I start drawing this on a chessboard, to see what this looks like.
>
>  It looks a bit like teeth, with the 4F representing the canine tooth (if you're a tiger, mine isn't that much bigger than my other teeth), and the last white (teeth are white) square that would follow is 8G, G being the 7th letter.
>
>  I'm not sure why your canine tooth would be black though unless you've just ripped into your prey (remember you're a tiger at this point) and the black is really red blood, or you've just eaten too many sugary sweets.

This kind of leaves a question as to

> Why the chess references are backwards. Well, that's because you're looking in the mirror while brushing.

Comment: Surely, the real question is how with my tiger paws am I able to play chess?

Comment: represents letters not letter.

Comment: It has nothing to do with my teeth.

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer

> 6

Because:

> The second parts are letters, 3H, 4F, 5H, 6G, 7H, 8?

So:

> To continue this patern, you'd have 8 to have an F, which is the equivalent of 6

Comment: Sounds a better fit than my answer +1

Comment: I don't understand why F is the next letter; could you make this clearer for those of us as stupid as I seem to be

Comment: Now that i'm thinking of it, it's not quite sure the patern is complete yet, so I guess it's just a hunch :S
I guess since he said that it wasn't eight, it had couldn't go up, so my guess is that it should go down again, but could be seven too

Comment: @foitn I forgot he had said it can't be 8. Looks like I'll go back to mulling it over (and getting nowhere) again

Comment: Wrong answer! well try......i said letters not letter.(should be my second hint)

Comment: @numberknot Oh shoot, you are right, I misread...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> 9

Because (Let x = Other insignificant numbers)

> 3, x, 4, x, 5, x, 6, x, 7, x, 8, x, 9

Comment: I feel so stupid. I will up vote as soon as I am able to.

Comment: Haha really? I thought no one was willing to give an answer because of how simple the puzzle was. But i think you may have made the puzzle more complex than what it actually was

Comment: Very kind of you.You're right I should just keep pretending I'm too clever to solve this puzzle rather than too stupid!

Comment: This gives the second missing number. It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AvikMohan I'm pretty sure it does answer it by fill in the question mark from the original question :)

Comment: Wrong answer.....it was a second missing number

Comment: Can you add spoilers?

Comment: @Teddysted You are miscounting. You are giving the number after the requested number.

Comment: Actually we have to find 12th number in the sequence, but @Tyler Johnson found 13th number..

Comment: @AvikMohan Oh... You're right... my bad